# Custom Icon for a C++ Program on the Unity Launcher - Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I am working on a program using C++ on Ubuntu 15.10. I am using Eclipse MARS.1 for my work environment. I am using GTK+ 3.18.2 for the interface stuff, and I build the project with GCC.

The program is complete, but there is one problem. When I build the program, and then run it (`sudo ./programname`) via Terminal, the program opens up and works, but the icon on the left toolbar in Ubuntu displays a question mark. Changing the actual executable file icon I can already do by simply right-clicking it and setting it to something different. Doing this gives me the same result.

[image]

I would like to change that to a custom icon I've made, which is a .xpm file. I've been doing hours of research to find a solution, but most of it is Windows based. I see how they do it in Windows. They have a resource.h file with the icon defined, typically something like this

```
icon.extensionname          128
<p>
file                        200
<p>
ect ect...
```

with the icon defined early above the rest.

So my question is, how do I add my icon so when I run the program, it displays on the Unity Launcher instead of the question-mark? Is there a resource file I need to make to define the .xpm file so when it is compiled, it will display it when I begin running the program, kind of like the Windows method?

Comment: There is no language C/C++, but there is a language C and a **different** language C++.. Which one is it?

Comment: My point was actually you should just remove the inappropriate tag. Regarding the question: this is off-topic, as it is not related to programming, by system configuration. Not sure about Gnome, but normally there should be a way to associate an icon with your application somewhere, at least that's how it works in KDE (and the underlying desktop data is often shared between the Linux desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the time and response Olaf, but might I would like to make a suggestion. If you have a point, then state it in the first post instead of dragging it out with multiple posts. 
The solution to the problem was to create a Desktop Entry script, and to add the pixmap icon to a specific directory. I made sure this was all automated by an install script that I wrote.

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=name of desktop entry
    Comment=insert comment
    Exec=name of .exe
    Icon=name of logo
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    Categories=Application;
```

Then I had to make changes to the install script I wrote. I will add the lines I included just for getting the pixmap icon and .exe put in the right place so it works.

```
    sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib
    sudo chmod 755 /etc/ld.so.conf
    sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/pixmaps
    sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications
    sudo cp -r ./6100-C-Test/pertechlogo.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps
    sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
    sudo cp -r ./6100-C-Test/gtktest /usr/bin
    sudo cp -r ./6100-C-Test/pertechlogo.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

Once the user installs the program, the icon will appear every-time they run it.